# SQL return email, if no email return phone number, if no phone number return cell (all one column)

Tags: sql, oracle

This an example I received but after research I still am stuck. He wants me to return the email address, if no email return telephone phone number, if no telephone number return cell (all one column). I have joined my tables but not sure if I should use a `WHERE NOT EXISTS` or an `IF`/`ELSE`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM entity e
LEFT OUTER JOIN telephone t ON t.id_number = e.id_number
LEFT OUTER JOIN email eml ON eml.id_number = e.id_number
```

Comment: You are on the right track with the left joins.  The function of happiness for this question is `coalesce`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [COALESCE function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm#SQLRF00617) that will return the first non-null value.

Answer (score 0):

you can use coalesce function which returns first not null result, not sure what do you mean by returning the cell, but i think you got the idea

```
 with xx as
     (select 'email@mail.com' email, null telephone, null cell
        from dual
      union all
      select null email, '123456' telephone, null cell
        from dual
      union all
      select null email, null telephone, '5' cell
        from dual)
    select coalesce(email, telephone, cell) first_not_null from xx
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting it to work like this:

```
CASE WHEN TRIM(eml.email_address) IS NOT NULL THEN eml.email_address

WHEN TRIM(t.telephone_number) IS NOT NULL THEN 'H: (' || t.area_code || ')'               || SUBSTR(t.telephone_number, 1, 3) || '-' || SUBSTR(t.telephone_number, 4, 4)

WHEN TRIM(t2.telephone_number) IS NOT NULL THEN 'C: (' || t2.area_code || ')' || SUBSTR(t2.telephone_number, 1, 3) || '-' || SUBSTR(t2.telephone_number, 4, 4) 

 ELSE 'No Email/Phone Found'

END AS "EMAIL/PHONE"
```

Answer (score -1):

This would be the answer :

```
SELECT Case When eml.emailaddress is not null then eml.emailaddress
            When eml.emailaddress IS NULL
             AND t.Phonenumber is NOT NULL THEN t.Phonenumber
            Else t.cellNumber
        End as ContactInfo 
  FROM entity e
       LEFT OUTER JOIN telephone t ON t.id_number = e.id_number
       LEFT OUTER JOIN email eml ON eml.id_number = e.id_number
```

Comment: What if I want the final else to be for the cellphone number and not the entity ID. I distinguish cellphone by saying t.telephone_type_code = 'C'...How would I replace that with the entity ID for the final else? Apologies I am very new to this!

Comment: The condition `eml.emailaddress IS NULL` is unnecessary in the second case. CASE WHEN operator stops after the first condition it evaluates to true. So if it is currently evaluation the second, it means the first one was false and therefore eml.emailaddress is already proven to be NULL.

Comment: SELECT Case When eml.emailaddress is not null then eml.emailaddress
            When t.Phonenumber is NOT NULL THEN t.Phonenumber
            When t.telephone_type_code = 'C' Then entity_ID
        End as ContactInfo 
  FROM entity e
       LEFT OUTER JOIN telephone t ON t.id_number = e.id_number
       LEFT OUTER JOIN email eml ON eml.id_number = e.id_number